# CSS Fixed Position overlapping each other

Tags: css

Basically I'm making a navigation bar and due to Jquery doing a lot of resizing to make a website look 'pretty' I don't want to use a horizontal list and so each button is created like so:

```
<a href="#" class="button" id="home"><img src="homeicon.png"><span id="homex"><br /><img src="home.png" /></span></a>
```

(yes they're all image buttons for good reason)

but the only problem is they're fixed and set to "top 0" at the top of the page and as a result cannot sit next to each other but rather overlap, any idea on how I can I still keep the position to fixed and they top to 0 yet keep them next to each other?

HTML

```
<div id="top">
<a href="#" class="button" id="home"><img src="homeicon.png"><span id="homex"><br /><img src="home.png" /></span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#top a.button { position: fixed; top: 0; padding: 12px; background: url('glacial_ice.jpg'); text-decoration: none; color: black; border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px; }
#top { position: relative; top:0; padding-left: 25px; }
```

Init function (runs on $(document).ready())

```
$('a.button').animate({
    height: '+=5px',
    }, 20, function() {
$('a.button').animate({
    opacity: 0.6,
    height: '-=5px',
}, 20);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need them centered, or do you care if they are in the right or left corner?

Comment: It doesn't really matter but I need them to be at the top of the page

Answer (score 3):

Put them all in a container, i.e. `id="header"`, give the header `position:fixed;top:0;etc...`

Then, for each of the link/buttons give them:

`position:relative;display:inline-block;float:left;`

if you want them centered, then in the `#header` use `text-align:center;` and remove `float:left` from the links

So the container will be fixed, but the buttons inside will be relative and not overlap.

hope this helps!

**very crude example**

http://jsfiddle.net/6SCTZ/

```
<div id="header">
   <div class="button">button1</div>
   <div class="button">button2</div>
   <div class="button">button3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header { position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;height:30px;background:black; text-align:center }

.button {position:relative;display:inline-block;color:white;margin:0 5px 0 5px;}
```

Comment: That works great as well, thank you so much for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

Just put whatever elements need to be fixed within a container element (in this case, I'll use a div with an ID of "top_fixed").

Consider the following html:

```
<div id='top_fixed'>
  <a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>
  <a href='http://yahoo.com'>Yahoo</a>
</div>
<div id='tall'></div>
```

Now, the following CSS:

```
a { display: inline; }
#top_fixed { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: auto; }
#tall {height: 2000px; background: #000;}
```

​

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mHKNc/1/

Comment: Excellent. Glad to have helped. :)