# Putting Many <div> Inside of One With position:fixed

Tags: css, html, position

I'm having an issue again. I just updated my Arcade page, and I want it to have a different navigational bar than the rest of my site. When I make every div that I'm using as a tab a `position:relative;` div, it works great. But I want the tabs to stay at the top wherever you are in the arcade.

I changed the tabs to `position:fixed` and it stopped working. Made all of my tabs overlap each other so you could only see one. I was researching this issue and found on article on it. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592458/css-fixed-position-overlapping-each-other) talks about putting all of the `position:relative` divs inside of one fixed position div. I tried and it isn't working.

I am using a PHP file to keep these tabs in.

This is my HTML in my header file:

```
<body>
    <br />
  <div id="gamenav-fixed"><center><a href="/"><div class="game-home">Home</div></a><a href="/arcade/action"><div class="game-nav">Action</div></a><a href="/arcade/arcade"><div class="game-nav">Arcade</div></a><a href="/arcade/puzzle"><div class="game-nav">Puzzle</div></a><a href="/arcade/vehicle"><div class="game-nav">Vehicle</div></a><a href="/arcade/violence"><div class="game-nav">Violence</div></a><a href="/arcade/defense"><div class="game-nav">Defense</div></a><a href="/arcade/rpg"><div class="game-nav">Role Playing</div></a><br /><br /></div>
  <div class="text-center"><font face="lucida console" size="12px" color="#686868">Game</font><font face="baskerville old face" size="12px" color="#888888"><b>Shank</b></font></br></br></div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS I'm using for these tabs:

```
/* The following is for the arcade page navigation! */
/* Center navigation. */
    div#gamenav-fixed:{
        position:fixed;
    }
    .game-nav{
        border:0px;
        padding:9px 25px 10px 25px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            transition: .5s;
            -moz-transition: .5s;
            -webkit-transition: .5s;
        font-family:arial;
        color:#909090;
        text-size:12px;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
        background-color:#e0e0e0;
    }
        .game-nav:hover{
            border:0px solid #686868;
                transition: .5;
                -moz-transition: .5;
                -webkit-transition: .5;
            background:#c0c0c0;
            color:#202020;
        }
            .game-nav:active{
                border:0px solid #686868;
                    transition: .5;
                    -moz-transition: .5;
                    -webkit-transition: .5;
                box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px #a0a0a0 inset;
                background:#d0d0d0;
                color:#202020;
            }
    .game-home{
        border:0px;
        padding:9px 25px 10px 25px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            transition: .5s;
            -moz-transition: .5s;
            -webkit-transition: .5s;
        font-family:arial;
        color:#202020;
        text-size:12px;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline;
        background-color:#c0c0c0;
        position:relative;
    }
        .game-home:hover{
            border:0px solid #686868;
                transition: .5;
                -moz-transition: .5;
                -webkit-transition: .5;
            background:#e0e0e0;
            color:#909090;
        }
            .game-home:active{
                border:0px solid #686868;
                    transition: .5;
                    -moz-transition: .5;
                    -webkit-transition: .5;
                box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 1px #a0a0a0 inset;
                background:#d0d0d0;
                color:#202020;
            }

/* Ends arcade navigation! */
```

My website is [gameshank.com](http://www.gameshank.com/). And thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you have an error in the CSS

```
div#gamenav-fixed:{
```

should be without the ":"

For me it is not overlapped then, and the only thing left id to set it to 100% so it is wide as the whole page and centered.

```
div#gamenav-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you have problems with this, could you paste the whole HTML ? maybe there is a problem with the doctype or sth similar, that could cause that the page is not renderer correctly in every browser. Maybe you could also state which browser you are using.

Here the jsfiddle proof that this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ed8T8/1/

Comment: It fixed it! How do I center it now?

Comment: for me the width:100% centered it

Comment: One last thing, sorry, how can I prevent the tabs from overlapping the GameShank text?

Comment: Add a padding to the body section (e.g. padding-top:30px) and set the top position of the menu manualy (e.g. top:10px)
See an example in my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ed8T8/1/

Comment: What is causing the page to act as if there are no margins set?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.. if you want to set margins, just set them like you wish on the body tag. If you want the menu to be more odd the top, just set the top position to someting else. As you declare it fixed, it can go out of the body margin area. try playing with the top posision.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38673/discussion-between-asped-and-austin-bunker)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your actual side (gameshank.com), your CSS should look like this:

```
.nav {
    /* ----- */
    margin: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    /* ----- */

    background: #989898;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #989898 0%, #d0d0d0 77%, #d0d0d0 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#989898), color-stop(77%,#d0d0d0), color-stop(100%,#d0d0d0));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #989898 0%,#d0d0d0 77%,#d0d0d0 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #989898 0%,#d0d0d0 77%,#d0d0d0 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #989898 0%,#d0d0d0 77%,#d0d0d0 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #989898 0%,#d0d0d0 77%,#d0d0d0 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#989898', endColorstr='#d0d0d0',GradientType=0 );
}
```